# Защита от снятия скрина экрана

Tags: клиент-сервер

В игровом клиенте есть функция автоскриншота - делает скрин каждый 4 минуты и отсылает в байтах на сервер - возможно ли перекрыть отправку скринов?Дело в том что скрины получаються не только игрового клиента,но и рабочего стола - боюсь "Улетит" что-нибудь важное :) - прошу если знаете что можно предпринять - говорите.

Comment: Играть на игровом компьютере, работать на рабочем. Не смешивать. С "боязно" -- к психологу.

Comment: @AK у меня пока что 1 пк

Comment: Если вам важна безопасность -- за неё нужно платить. Платить вы не готовы, видимо. Ну тогда решение для бедных: не забывайте разворачивать игру на весь экран.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не относится к программированию или системному администрированию.

Comment: @AK, ну вроде что-то типа администрирования...

Comment: @AK, к кибербезопасности относится, если дополнить, то ещё и к реверсинжинирингу. Вопрос надо закрыть потому что он не раскрыт, плохой по качеству.

Comment: Устанавливай win 10 или что-то из линуксов - у них всех есть функция "новый рабочий стол"

Comment: @strangerintheday спасибо,но не подходит

Comment: @Gapsy201 чем? проще, чем пытаться как-то хитро вывернуться

Comment: @strangerintheday ну как бы я задал вопрос как запретить это все в C# - но почему-то перенесли в клиент-сервер

Comment: А чем этот вопрос относится к c# или к javascript? Я тоже хотел убрать эту метку, но eri опередил.

Comment: @AK, комментарии к ответу посмотри. Он хочет подменять dll, которая делает скриншоты.

Comment: @Qwertiy Уже подменил ) загружаю свою ДО загрузки основной - в итоге моя грузиться и работа идет с моей длл

Answer (score 0):

Выбирай:

1. Берёшь любой файрволл и настраиваешь запрет обращения к соответствующему адресу.
2. В файле hosts написать другой ip, чтобы было нельзя послать скриншот.
3. Запускаешь локальный поркси (если игра его использует) и обрабатываешь как-то на нём - сбрасываешь, либо подменяешь ответ на статический. Либо подменяешь тело запроса, а дальше прокидываешь серверу.
4. Делаешь свой сервер (на localhost) и через hosts или прокси переадресуешь запрос к нему. В отличие от предыдущих вариантов позволяет не обрывать соединение, а что-то отдавать игре, чтобы она не падала из-за ошибки соединения.

Comment: dll качается по сети - ее не видно,но можно сдампить.Если начну что-то менять буду получать ошибку что файлы модифицированны

Comment: а возможно ли подменить dll?она находиться в Списке Assembly

Comment: @Gapsy201, не dll менять, а перехватывать отправку скрина и либо не пропускать на сервер, либо подменять скрин и слать другой.

Comment: можете подсказать материал по перехвату?Возможно получиться подменить эту dll в памяти и заменить на свою